# How to calculate sum of individual column value with group mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I can group some mongodb document using `aggregate` method but I need to calculate sum of column value as per group. I am explaining my mongodb document below.

```
 {
                "Region": "EMEAR",
                "Theatre": "Europe South",
                "Customer": "NSO-OTE",
                "Test Type": "Functional",
                "Test Sub-type": "Acceptance",
                "Manual/Auto": "Manual",
                "Report Date": "Q3 FY21",
                "CFD": "0",
                "TC Passed": "1",
                "TC Failed": "0",
                "TC Blocked": "0"
            },
            {
                "Region": "EMEAR",
                "Theatre": "Europe South",
                "Customer": "NSO-OTE",
                "Test Type": "Functional",
                "Test Sub-type": "Acceptance",
                "Manual/Auto": "Manual",
                "Report Date": "Q3 FY21",
                "CFD": "0",
                "TC Passed": "1",
                "TC Failed": "0",
                "TC Blocked": "0"
            },
            {
                "Region": "EMEAR",
                "Theatre": "Europe South",
                "Customer": "NSO-OTE",
                "Test Type": "Functional",
                "Test Sub-type": "Acceptance",
                "Manual/Auto": "Manual",
                "Report Date": "Q3 FY21",
                "CFD": "0",
                "TC Passed": "1",
                "TC Failed": "0",
                "TC Blocked": "0"
            },
            {
                "Region": "EMEAR",
                "Theatre": "Europe South",
                "Customer": "NSO-OTE",
                "Test Type": "Functional",
                "Test Sub-type": "Acceptance",
                "Manual/Auto": "Automated",
                "Report Date": "Q3 FY21",
                "CFD": "0",
                "TC Passed": "0",
                "TC Failed": "0",
                "TC Blocked": "1"
            },
            {
                "Region": "EMEAR",
                "Theatre": "Europe South",
                "Customer": "NSO-OTE",
                "Test Type": "Functional",
                "Test Sub-type": "Acceptance",
                "Manual/Auto": "Manual",
                "Report Date": "Q3 FY21",
                "CFD": "0",
                "TC Passed": "1",
                "TC Failed": "0",
                "TC Blocked": "0"
            }
```

This is my document. I am running the following query to group it.

```
db.getCollection('emer').aggregate([
    {
        "$group":{
            "_id": {
                "Region": "$Region",
                "Theatre": "$Theatre",
                "Customer": "$Customer",
                "Test Type": "$Test Type",
                "Test Sub-type": "$Test Sub-type",
                "Manual/Auto": "$Manual/Auto",
                "Report Date": "$Report Date"
            },
            "data" : {"$first" : "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Region": "$data.Region",
            "Theatre": "$data.Theatre",
            "Customer": "$data.Customer",
            "Test Type": "$data.Test Type",
            "Test Sub-type": "$data.Test Sub-type",
            "Manual/Auto": "$data.Manual/Auto",
            "Report Date": "$data.Report Date",
            "CFD" : "$data.CFD",
            "TC Passed" : "$data.TC Passed",
            "TC Failed" : "$data.TC Failed",
            "TC Blocked" : "$data.TC Blocked",
        }
    }
])
```

Here I can easily group the record as per thr grouping condition. But I need the `sum of` `CFD, TC Passed, TC Failed, TC Blocked` column value as per the above grouping. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should put `$sum` in your `$group` stage instead of doing it afterwards.
In your current attempts, you are only sampling 1 document per group and get the sum from that document only.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Region": "$Region",
        "Theatre": "$Theatre",
        "Customer": "$Customer",
        "Test Type": "$Test Type",
        "Test Sub-type": "$Test Sub-type",
        "Manual/Auto": "$Manual/Auto",
        "Report Date": "$Report Date"
      },
      "CFD": {
        $sum: "$data.CFD"
      },
      "TC Passed": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$TC Passed"
        }
      },
      "TC Failed": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$TC Failed"
        }
      },
      "TC Blocked": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$TC Blocked"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wGNPbkD0emo) for your reference.

Comment: its working in Mongo playground but in robo3t its showing invalid pipeline operator.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? Its probably related to `$toInt` I used, which are available on MongoDB 4.0+

Comment: version 3.6 i am using

Comment: You may need to convert your fields (i.e. `CFD, TC Passed, TC Failed, TC Blocked`) to integer type first through other means first. If the fields are meant to be used in calculation, storing them as String is considered anti-pattern anyway.